# How to drag and drop a file unto a row with ag-grid?

Tags: drag-and-drop, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am working on a prototype of how we might use ag-grid to enhance one of our applications.  I would like to drag and drop a file from my desktop unto a particular row of the ag-grid.  The use case is adding an attachment to a particular project which is represented as a row.  I have read a lot about drag and drop in general, so I know the file portion of the ask is doable.  However, when I search for drag and drop with regards to ag-grid, it is always about dragging columns or rows.  I'm dragging something outside of the grid on to the grid.  We are using the angular implementation of ag-grid if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be possible if you create your own cell renderer, you will need to add all the logic for the grag & drop though

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Hope this helps

Comment: Good suggestion.  The cell can process the dropped file.  However, to really make things work, I need to access services outside of the renderer.  Apparently, dependency injection isn't available because the registration of the renderer complains whenever the constructor has a parameter.